# Calculate how many times a person completes a task in a date range Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, date-range

I'm trying to calculate how many times a person completes a task in a date range Excel? I can get part but not all of it.

For example For Admin 1, I'd like them to confirm a task is complete (data validation drop down) and then enter the date.

I want to count the dates for that person by the week and so the date range would be 01/01/2022 to 17/01/2022.

Any help appreciated.
Many thanks.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good place for a Pivot Table solution.

Using the following table that is a similar format to yours:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqnxA.png)

You can go to the insert tab and in the Tables section select PivotTable. Use the defaults.

[PivotTable Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1QTI.png)

This will allow you to start creating the Pivot Table. From here you can place Date in Rows, Person in Columns, and Confirm Task Complete into values.

[Proper PivotTable Arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvOsd.png)

You can group the date by clicking on any date value and selecting Group Selection in the Analyze tab. Group by Month and you should get a result similar to what you expect.